# struts 2 File Upload and Save problem

Tags: struts2

The file is uploaded successfully but it is not getting saved

This is the function in my action class

```
public String uploadPhoto()
{
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String filePath = request.getContextPath();
    File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
        Users user =   userDao.findByUsername((String)session.get("username"));
        user.setPhotoName(filePath+userImageFileName);
        userDao.save(user);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        addActionError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return INPUT;
    }

    return "UPLOADED";
}
```

I used breakpoints and all statements are executed successfully

But I see no file in my context root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was setting an incorrect path

Instead of

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
String filePath = request.getContextPath();
```

it should be

```
String filePath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sumit!!

Struts2 has build in file upload functionality and you can use that one very easily.use that build in interceptor to upload files.
Here is the link for the same

[File Upload](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/file-upload-interceptor.html.)

This interceptor will make available you the file content and now in Action class its your approach how you will save the file using IO system.

Also note that struts2 will put the file in the temp context and it will clean up the context when interceptor will be called in reverse order so make sure to save the uploaded file using IO

Comment: i did exactly that, i said that image is uploading fine, but when i am saving it using      FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate); it is not getting saved Please read the question carefully before responding

Comment: Just check the size of the content being uploaded by the Struts2 interceptor and if thats correct there is some problem in the file saving way.Struts only providing you the way to upload the file and place it in the temp area how you save that is not in its scope so just check this aspect hope it will help you